# django redirecting back to the page from where the request was made

Tags: python, django, redirect

I implemented in django return  to original page via redirect see view example

```
@login_required
def category_edit(request, pk,uri):
    post = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            category = form.save(commit=False)
            category.author = request.user
            category.creation_time  = timezone.now()
            category.save()
            return redirect(uri)
            #return redirect('category_details', pk=post.id)
    else:
        form = CategoryForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'item/category_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

So basically after each operation like edit,new I redirect back to from where the call was originally made. (I stoped using it in case of delete since in case of delete the page might not exist any more)

However in one of my questons somebody mentioned that it is better approach to add a path to URL instead of sending URL as parameter to add it in the link

```
  <a href="{% url 'category_delete' pk=category.id %}?next={{request.path}}">Delete</a>
```

From samples and documentation I figured out this approach should automatically work in django if I have  in my settings in  'context_processors' included  'django.template.context_processors.request'. (However the samples I saw where dated to previous versions of Django)

But this approach  didn't work. So my question is does ?next={{request.path}} is still supported in Django 1.8 and if yes what step I am missing.

Any feedback on what approach is better the redirect or the ?next={{request.path}} is welcome as well.

Comment: You need to provide the source that says `this approach should automatically work in django`, I'm interested to see it.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment on the other question. I was saying that it would be better to include the next url as a GET parameter e.g. `/category/1/delete/?next=/home/` rather than in the url itself e.g. `/category/1/delete/home/`. It's up to you to fetch the value from `request.GET` and return a redirect, Django certainly does not do this for you.

Comment: Note also that you shouldn't automatically trust a redirect location provided in the url - it's a security risk. Django has an `is_safe_url` utility. See [this blog post](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2012/dec/10/security/) for more info.

Comment: Ok , thanks @Alasdair  it clears it out. I guess my mined  want into wrong direction  and I misunderstood other stackoverflow answers (@Shang disregard it )